# avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout Error for Arduino UNO

Tags: avr, arduino-uno, avrdude

I am compiling and uploading sketch through command line. I have built a .CPP file as under:

```
#include< WProgram.h>

int led = 13;
void setup() {                
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  
  delay(10000);               
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);   
  delay(1000);               
}
```

Now i compiled using command: make TARGET=file_1402814559284 and it compiled fine. When i uploaded using command: make upload TARGET=file_1402814559284

```
avrdude -F -p atmega328p -P \\.\COM121 -c stk500 -b 115200 -C"avrdude.conf"  -U
flash:w:file_1402814559284.hex
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude: stk500v2_command(): failed miserably to execute command 0x10
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA328P is 1E 95 0F
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
```

Please suggest me how to resolve the problem. Code is easily uploaded using arduino IDE but through command line its a problem. I am using Arduino UNO atmega328p and no wiring is done. I am just checking the uploading part.

```
Make file i am using:
# Arduino makefile
# $Id$
SHELL=C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
PORT = \\.\COM121
#/dev/tty.USB*
ARDUINO = arduino
SRC = $(ARDUINO)/buffer.c $(ARDUINO)/pins_arduino.c \
  $(ARDUINO)/Serial.c $(ARDUINO)/uart.c $(ARDUINO)/wiring.c
CXXSRC = $(TARGET).cpp $(ARDUINO)/HardwareSerial.cpp $(ARDUINO)/WRandom.cpp
MCU = atmega328p
F_CPU = 16000000
FORMAT = ihex
UPLOAD_RATE = 115200

# Name of this Makefile (used for "make depend").
MAKEFILE = Makefile

# Debugging format.
# Native formats for AVR-GCC's -g are stabs [default], or dwarf-2.
# AVR (extended) COFF requires stabs, plus an avr-objcopy run.
DEBUG = stabs

OPT = s

# Place -D or -U options here
CDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)
CXXDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)

# Place -I options here
CINCS = -I$(ARDUINO)
CXXINCS = -I$(ARDUINO)

# Compiler flag to set the C Standard level.
# c89   - "ANSI" C
# gnu89 - c89 plus GCC extensions
# c99   - ISO C99 standard (not yet fully implemented)
# gnu99 - c99 plus GCC extensions
CSTANDARD = -std=gnu99
CDEBUG = -g$(DEBUG)
CWARN = -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
CTUNING = -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums
#CEXTRA = -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:.c=.lst)

CFLAGS = $(CDEBUG) $(CDEFS) $(CINCS) -O$(OPT) $(CWARN) $(CSTANDARD) $(CEXTRA)
CXXFLAGS = $(CDEFS) $(CINCS) -O$(OPT)
#ASFLAGS = -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:.S=.lst),-gstabs 
LDFLAGS = 


# Programming support using avrdude. Settings and variables.
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER = stk500
AVRDUDE_PORT = $(PORT)
AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH = -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex
AVRDUDE_FLAGS =-F -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER) \
  -b $(UPLOAD_RATE) -C"avrdude.conf" 


# Program settings
# Program settings
CC = avr-gcc
CXX = avr-g++
OBJCOPY = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP = avr-objdump
SIZE = avr-size
NM = avr-nm
AVRDUDE = avrdude
REMOVE = rm -f
MV = mv -f

# Define all object files.
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o) $(CXXSRC:.cpp=.o) $(ASRC:.S=.o)

# Define all listing files.
LST = $(ASRC:.S=.lst) $(CXXSRC:.cpp=.lst) $(SRC:.c=.lst)

# Combine all necessary flags and optional flags.
# Add target processor to flags.
ALL_CFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS)
ALL_CXXFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CXXFLAGS)
ALL_ASFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. -x assembler-with-cpp $(ASFLAGS)


# Default target.
all: build

build: elf hex eep

elf: $(TARGET).elf
hex: $(TARGET).hex
eep: $(TARGET).eep
lss: $(TARGET).lss 
sym: $(TARGET).sym

# Program the device.  
upload: $(TARGET).hex $(TARGET).eep
    $(AVRDUDE) $(AVRDUDE_FLAGS) $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH)




# Convert ELF to COFF for use in debugging / simulating in AVR Studio or VMLAB.
COFFCONVERT=$(OBJCOPY) --debugging \
--change-section-address .data-0x800000 \
--change-section-address .bss-0x800000 \
--change-section-address .noinit-0x800000 \
--change-section-address .eeprom-0x810000 


coff: $(TARGET).elf
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-avr $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).cof


extcoff: $(TARGET).elf
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-ext-avr $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).cof


.SUFFIXES: .elf .hex .eep .lss .sym

.elf.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) -R .eeprom $< $@

.elf.eep:
    -$(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" \
    --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O $(FORMAT) $< $@

# Create extended listing file from ELF output file.
.elf.lss:
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -S $< > $@

# Create a symbol table from ELF output file.
.elf.sym:
    $(NM) -n $< > $@



# Link: create ELF output file from object files.
$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $(OBJ) --output $@ $(LDFLAGS)


# Compile: create object files from C++ source files.
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

# Compile: create object files from C source files.
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 


# Compile: create assembler files from C source files.
.c.s:
    $(CC) -S $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Assemble: create object files from assembler source files.
.S.o:
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_ASFLAGS) $< -o $@



# Target: clean project.
clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).hex $(TARGET).eep $(TARGET).cof $(TARGET).elf \
    $(TARGET).map $(TARGET).sym $(TARGET).lss \
    $(OBJ) $(LST) $(SRC:.c=.s) $(SRC:.c=.d) $(CXXSRC:.cpp=.s) $(CXXSRC:.cpp=.d)

depend:
    if grep '^# DO NOT DELETE' $(MAKEFILE) >/dev/null; \
    then \
        sed -e '/^# DO NOT DELETE/,$$d' $(MAKEFILE) > \
            $(MAKEFILE).$$$$ && \
        $(MV) $(MAKEFILE).$$$$ $(MAKEFILE); \
    fi
    echo '# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend depends on it.' \
        >> $(MAKEFILE); \
    $(CC) -M -mmcu=$(MCU) $(CDEFS) $(CINCS) $(SRC) $(ASRC) >> $(MAKEFILE)

.PHONY: all build elf hex eep lss sym program coff extcoff clean depend
```